# How do I customize the steps of the progress bar on Magento 2 Checkout?

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs

I would like to quite simply change the "shipping" step on the magento 2 checkout to read "delivery information".

I tried to do it through translation to no avail. I am wonder can anyone point me towards which template or xml needs to extended and edited to customize the steps' names please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translations JS/HTML files are extremely unreliable as you've noticed, to change this without using translations you'll need to either add a [JS mixin](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html) for the initialize function or overwrite the whole file:

```
/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js
```

If you look on line 85 you'll see this:

```
stepNavigator.registerStep(
    'shipping',
    '',
    $t('Shipping'),
    this.visible, _.bind(this.navigate, this),
    10
);
```

You'll want to change Shipping to Delivery Information.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the checkout step text by translation csv

Put the text **Shipping,delivery information** in below **en_US.csv** path

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/i18n/en_US.csv

Run below commnad and check your changes

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Comment: Sorry,  Suresh - but this is not helpful as the progress bar is not available to translations because it written in the js, I think. I mentioned that it was not possible to do via translation in my question.